# How to install pyspark without hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, pyspark

I want to install pyspark but I don't want to use hadoop because I just want to test out some functions. I followed instructions from a bunch of websites: I used pip to install pyspark, installed jdk 8 and set JAVA_PATH, SPARK_HOME, PATH variables but it's not working.

My program is:

```
from pyspark import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

I am getting this exception:

```
\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin\java was unexpected at this time.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ankit\Untitled-1.py", line 4, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  File "C:\Users\ankit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 228, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "C:\Users\ankit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 384, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "C:\Users\ankit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 144, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "C:\Users\ankit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 331, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "C:\Users\ankit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 108, in launch_gateway
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

Comment: Seems like you configured one of your variables wrong, based on `\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin\java was unexpected at this time`... Can you clarify what exactly you changed?

Comment: Yes, there is a space in `JAVA_HOME`, plus the JDK path is wrong or the JDK 8 bitness is wrong.